# r-plotly - Need some advice

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

How can I use `library(plotly)` in R to bring the following plot into the web?

```
library(quantregGrowth)
data(growthData)
m6<-gcrq(y~ps(x, lambda=seq(0,100,l=20)), tau=c(0.025,0.975), n.boot=10, 
data=growthData)
plot(m6)
```

Comment: Do you mean "how do I save this as an image"?

Comment: @ usr2564301, thanks for the comment, No I want to bring the plot into the web by using plotly library

Comment: Is "bring a plot into the web" some terminology specific to R?

Comment: @ usr2564301, I want to have a plot something like https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

temp <- data.frame(m6$fitted)
growthData_b <- cbind(growthData, temp)
```

Option 1 is to use `ggplotly()`:

```
a <- ggplot(data=growthData_b, aes(x, y=X0.025)) + 
geom_line() + 
geom_line(data=growthData_b, aes(x, y=X0.975), color = "red")  + theme_bw() + 
ylab('fitted')
ggplotly(a)
```

Option 2 is to use `plot_ly()`:

```
plot_ly() %>% add_lines(data = growthData_b, x = ~x, y = ~X0.025) %>% add_lines(data = growthData_b, x = ~x, y = ~X0.975)
```

Comment: If you also can explain how R brings "plot into the web" (in non-R terms, please), then you have yourself an upvote :)

Comment: @usr2564301 if you read his answer to your comment you will understand what he is trying to do...but something, like lost in translation, might be good here :-)

Comment: @ MLavoie, thanks for the great suggestion. I will accept your solution. But just a question how can I modify your code when I have several curves on a plot. Please run my data again (I edited the question to have the information of two percentiles in a plot). I have an error when I use ggplotly(a) to bring the new plot into the web.

Comment: @shoo. There are a few possibilities but here is one (see edits).  What was the error with ggplotly()?

Comment: @shoo as suggested in the comment, you need to load your app on a server (shinyapps, amazon, or you own)